# Ejecutar primero el contenido de un archivo.js

Tags: javascript, html

Cómo se logra que el contenido de un archivo .js se ejecute primero, antes el contenido que hay en html.
He seguido ejemplos con window.onload = nombre_de_la_funcion. Pero no ha funcionado

Comment: ¿Intentaste agregar el script en el `<head>`? si eso es a lo que te refieres... Por otro lado, el evento `onload` se ejecutará cuando el DOM haya cargado, documentación aquí: [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: @C.Rodriguez no habían intentatado cargarlo en el head, me habían enseñado que se ponen al final del body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando necesites cargar **código `js` importante** antes que cargue el DOM de tu documento, se debe agregar el script respectivo en el `<head>` de tu documento.

Es totalmente cierto, que cargarlos antes de cerrar el `body` es más efectivo, puesto que te ahorra tiempo de carga y eso beneficiará el SEO de tu sitio, sin embargo, es más recomendable analizar el código que estés agregando en tu sitio, y valorar si debe ir en el `<head>` o al final del `<body>`.

Aquí tienes un buen ejemplo (mira la respuesta #1):

- [¿Por qué es recomendable usar el script en el head?](https://uniwebsidad.com/foro/pregunta/11/por-que-es-recomendable-usar-el-script-en-el-head/)